# I want to remove the route login without interfering with my login, Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-7

I used the auth controllers to make my login in /admin but I want to remove the route that goes to /login but if I try it, this gives me this error:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>   The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
>   http://casarelvas.test/admin

and my web.php looks like this:

```php
Route::get('/admin', function () {
    return view('login');
})->name('login');
```

but if I let them to my admin (login) work when I go for /login gives me this error because I deleted the blade files because I dont want it:

> Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
>   View [layouts.app] not found. (View: C:\laragon\www\casarelvas\resources\views\auth\login.blade.php)
>   http://casarelvas.test/login

(it also happens when I log out)

and my web.php looks like this:

```php
Route::get('/admin', function () {
    return view('login');
})->name('login');
Auth::routes();
Auth::routes(['register' => false]);
```

maybe the solution is to hide the route and make / login give a 404 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On vendor/ui/auth-backend/AuthenticatesUsers.php you can change this:

```php
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }
```

So I solved my question by changing to this:

```php
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        abort(404);
    }
```

And stay with web.php like this:

```php
Route::get('/admin', function () {
    return view('login');
})->name('admin-login');
Auth::routes();
Auth::routes(['register' => false]);
```

I had to change the name to not interfere with a route named login that's registered somewhere.

Comment: if you got a better solution please answer

Answer (score 0):

Laravel doesn't provide a direct wayout to override the login route name. What you can do here folllowing:

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('login', function () {
    abort(404);
});
Route::get('admin', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')
    ->name('login');
```

Comment: but now gives me this error because LoginController@showLoginForm return the wrong view, I think.

>Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
View [layouts.app] not found. (View: C:\laragon\www\casarelvas\resources\views\auth\login.blade.php)
http://casarelvas.test/admin

Comment: If you dont want to use laravel's loginController, you can just use custom route callback which in this case would be:

Route::get('admin', function () {
            return view('login');
        })->name('login');

Comment: What u did in your solution (next answer) is also correct. That handles it in controller whereas the above solution throws 404 when the routes are registered. Additionally, you can name your new route ("admin") as "login"